# How can repetitive variable checking be streamlined?

Tags: python

I often have to execute some function, save the output, and depending on what the output was, do different things. And then later on use the output as input to more functions.

**It results in a very specific pattern of code.**

I feel like I'm missing something simple. 
... as if some logic here could be somehow streamlined. The variable declaration, variable checking, and forthcoming execution of other stuff onto said variable seems almost redundant.

(tried to make the code as applicable to everyone and as applicable to every application, as possible)
**here's some sample code that fits this predicament:**

```
    some_sort_of_data=validate(var1, 'type1')       
    if some_sort_of_data.is_bad:
        return some_sort_of_data.is_bad

    more_data=validate(var2, 'type2')
    if more_data.is_bad:
        return more_data.is_bad

    get_special_info=get_parent_of_item(some_sort_of_data.validated_item)
    if get_special_info['error']:
        return get_special_info['data']

    if not (has_access_rights() or
        special_relationship(more_data.validated_item) or 
        some_sort_of_other_permissions(get_special_info['result'])):
            return "Blah Blah blah some sort of incompatibility"

    new_status_result=change_status(some_sort_of_data.validated_item, more_data.validated_item)
    if new_status_result['error']
        return new_status_result['result']

    # If we've passed all the previous checks and managed to get all the way here..
    return "yay did a thing successfully"
```

... is it just me or do you also see how such a pattern feels *off*? If so, how can it best be streamlined?

edit: I know in some other languages you can streamline it a bit by writing

```
if (some_sort_of_data=validate(var1, 'type1')=="success")
    return some_sort_of_data.some_class_variable
```

instead of

```
some_sort_of_data=validate(var1, 'type1')       
if some_sort_of_data=="success":
    return some_sort_of_data.some_class_variable
```

but that's still not enough and *still quite redundant*, right?

Comment: Throwing exceptions is often a better way to deal with this, so you don't have to write error checks after every call. Just put everything inside a big `try/except`.

Comment: @Barmar so like ........ have every single one of those throw a different **type** of error, and then at the end you can handle all the errors in different ways (or in one way altogether) ? is that what you're getting at? It would help me greatly if you could throw code snippet - I learn well via example. (you could do it as a question answer ofc)

Comment: @Barmar ah! thought of one more thing! What if the if-statment is checking for something that isn't an error - such as something benign, like checking whether the user is of typeA or typeB. Lets say the text is phrased differently depending on user type (something benign, non errorlike) I'm not sure I should handle such cases via error-catching .. or should I?

Comment: Python 3.8 introduces an assignment expression just for this use case.

Comment: There's no one size fits all solution for this, you need to design whatever is appropriate for your use case. Data validation is often quite repetitive, since you need to do different validation for each input. Sometimes a data-driven approach can be useful -- you can have a list of validation types and loop through them.

Comment: This type of general design advice is not really appropriate for [so]. It might be a slightly better fit for [softwareengineering.se]. And if you have actual working code that you're looking for help cleaning up, [codereview.se] would be more appropriate.